# Exibir conteúdo (somente uma vez) após X repetições no PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php do { ?>
<div>Área que desejo repetição</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Gostaria que, após 2 repetições, fosse exibido um conteúdo extra. Somente após 2 repetições e não a cada 2 repetições.

Exemplo de output:

```
<div>Área que desejo repetição</div>
<div>Área que desejo repetição</div>
<div>Área do conteúdo EXTRA</div>
<div>Área que desejo repetição</div>
<div>Área que desejo repetição</div>
<div>Área que desejo repetição</div>
...
```

PS: Já fiz uma pergunta semelhante anteriormente mas não consegui adaptar a este cenário. Obrigado.

Comment: `if ($contador == 2) { echo '<div>ABC</div>'; }  $contador++;`

Answer (score 2):

Basta verificar qual pulo o loop esta.

Percorra a quantidade necessária, com um `if` você verifica qual nível atual e executa o que deseja.

```
<?php

$nivel = 1; // vamos começar pelo nível 1

while ($nivel <= 10 /* vamos percorrer 10 niveis */) {

   /* se o nivel for o segundo, ou seja,
   loop ter sido executado duas vezes já
   ele irá executar esta parte do código */

   if($nivel == 2){ 
      // do something...        
   }

  echo $nivel++;  /* vamos imprimir o nivel atual */
}
```

Exemplo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/98eda8a46d13828330bd3a69fa0d410f6f64924b

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar um laço `for` ou `while` para as repetições e usar um `if` para verificar a posição do contador com o rray colocou nos comentários:

Exemplo para `for`:

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i <$repetições ; $i++): ?>
    <div>Área que desejo repetição</div>
    <?php if ($i == 2):?>
        <div>Área do conteúdo EXTRA</div>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Exemplo com `while`:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>                    
<?php while ($i <= $repetições): ?>                 
    <div>Área que desejo repetição</div>
    <?php if ($i == 2):?>
        <div>Área do conteúdo EXTRA</div>
    <?php endif;?>      
    <?php $i++;?>       
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Veja qual se adequa melhor ao seu problema.

Qualquer dúvida é só falar.

Att;